# Groovy concurrency

Tags: multithreading, groovy

I have a question to Groovy threads.

My task is to translate each file in a given directory in a certain manner
and place the resulting output in a file in an other directory.

I wrote the following code, which works:

```
static def translateDir(fromDir, targetDir) {
    def allFiles = new File(fromDir).listFiles()
    def numFiles = allFiles.length

    for (i in 0..(numFiles - 1))
        translate(allFiles[i].getAbsolutePath(), targetDir)
}
```

Now, I tried to parallelize this code like this:

```
static def translateDir(fromDir, targetDir) {
    def allFiles = new File(fromDir).listFiles()
    def numFiles = allFiles.length
    def numCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()

    for (i in 0..(numCores - 1)) {
        println("Thread " + i + "starting")
        Thread.start {
            for (def j = i; j < numFiles; j += numCores) {
                println("j = " + j) 
                translate(allFiles[j].getAbsolutePath(), targetDir)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which does not work and provides the output:

```
Thread 0 starting
Thread 1 starting
Thread 2 starting
Thread 3 starting
```

nunCores is 4, and numFiles is 3 in my test case.
What is going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok, 2 things:

1. Inside of the thread's implicit run() method, you are referencing the 'i' variable. I'd have to step it through a debugger to see exactly what happens, but technically, you shouldn't even have access to 'i' there, because it's not final. So, I'd suggest creating a Runnable object to which you pass 'i' in the constructor. Then start the runnable on the thread.
2. Groovy has great concurrency support - no reason to roll your own like this. Take a look at [GPars](http://gpars.github.io/)

Comment: You will have access to `i`, it doesn't need to be final in Groovy, but it most likely won't have the value you require

Comment: @greybeardedgeek The GPars link requires a login.

Comment: @dbush - clearly, someone there has changed something (I'm guessing that it has to do with Groovy's recent transition.
In the meantime, the source is still available at https://github.com/GPars/GPars and the documentation is at http://gpars.org/1.2.1/javadoc/index.html

Answer (score 11):

You're starting threads, but then your program finishes before they run.

As it shows in [the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Concurrency+with+Groovy), you need to call `join` on the threads to wait for them to complete

It's probably easier to use the executor framework, which is shown further down on that same page

---

#### Edit

Just for fun, I implemented something using `Thread.start` that does what you are trying to achieve

```
// This will perform the task required for a list of files
def translate( List files ) {
  files.each {
    // We will just print it out, and sleep for a bit
    println it
    Thread.sleep( 300 )
  }
}

// makeWorker returns a closure that will process the files
def makeWorker( List files ) {
  { -> translate( files ) }
}

// Main processing function
void process( List files ) {
  int numCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
  // Split the files to process into groups (one for each worker)
  def partitioned = (0..<numCores).collect { i ->
    files[ (i..<files.size()).step( numCores ) ]
  }
  // Then create a Thread for each group
  def threads = partitioned.collect { group ->
    Thread.start makeWorker( group )
  }
  // And wait for them all to finish
  threads*.join()
}

// Simulate the process with the letters a through z
process( 'a'..'z' )
```