# Groovy/SoapUI: Loop inside thread does not work

Tags: multithreading, groovy, soapui

I'm doing smth like:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = requestList.iterator()

    (1..threadCount).each {

        Thread.start {

            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                log.info iterator.next()
                Thread.sleep(50)
            }
        }
    }
```

Given that `threadCount = 10` and `requestList is ~115`, I expect all threads to output all the list, each time asking iterator to give them next.

**However, I hardly even get 10 logs, usually 8.**

Everything is done inside SoapUI groovy script step, instead of log.info I actually plan triggering a REST request with number N.

What am I doing wrong with these threads?

**UPD**

Okay, did smth stupid like this, to test (and avoid using one array):

```
def array1 = all[0..5]
def array2 = all[6..11]


Thread.start{

    for(String r: array1) {
        log.info r
    }
}

Thread.start{

    for(String r: array2) {
        log.info r
    }
}
```

And now I have no output at all or one log at most, though I expect 12.
How do I create threads that will output data simultaneously?

**EVEN MORE**

```
def threadCount=10

(0..threadCount).each { n ->

 Thread.start {

  (1..10).each {
       log.info "thread"+n+" says| "+it
  }
 }
}
```

Output is:

```
thread0 says| 1
thread3 says| 1
thread8 says| 1
thread2 says| 1
thread1 says| 1
thread9 says| 1
thread7 says| 1
thread5 says| 1
thread4 says| 1
thread0 says| 2
```

And nothing more. Again, what's wrong with me or groovy? (hope groovy is fine)

Comment: This will lead to race condition and a data race as well because the iterator object is shared by all threads without any synchronization. So the output is unpredictable.

Comment: You stumbled upon a thread safety issue. A related question is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847939/is-list-iterator-thread-safe

Comment: About your update, define the arrays properly to see the output you are expecting: def array1 = 0..5. In the for loop you should use Integer, but String will work as well.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790813/groovy-concurrency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, problem is that SoapUI kills main thread before all threads have an opportunity to grab their next number.

A quick way to live with this is to add `sleep` to main method